# ArrayList being empty after adding elements

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have this android code which bring a JSON from a server and fill an ArrayList from that JSON
I checked the size of the ArrayList "meals" inside the onresponse void it gives me 1 but when i check it after the StringRequest object i get 0 items .
meals is defined in global scope and initialized inside the oncreateview function
The Code:

```
               public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
Log.i("debug","on create view");
View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meal_list,container,false);
ListView List ;
meals=new ArrayList<meal>();
String url="http://syriankitchen.tk/get_recent.php";
StringRequest mealsrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try{
            JSONObject object= new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray mealsArray = object.getJSONArray("result");
            for(int i=0;i<mealsArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject cur = mealsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int id= cur.getInt("id");
                String name= cur.getString("name");
                String description = cur.getString("description");
                int price = cur.getInt("price");
                meals.add(new meal(id,name,price,description));
            }
            Log.i("debug","meals size = "+meals.size());
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
},new Response.ErrorListener(){
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(mealsrequest);
ArrayList<String> strs=new ArrayList<String>();
String mealsnames[]=new String[meals.size()];
for(int i=0;i<meals.size();i++)strs.add(meals.get(i).getName());
strs.toArray(mealsnames);
Log.i("debug","meals ou size "+meals.size());
CustomList  adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(),mealsnames,meals);
List = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
List.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you are confused as to what `after` means. callbacks are asynchronous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is about understanding how `asynchronous` tasks work. When you are adding a `volley` request to the queque, it will run in **background thread** (off the main thread) and control will pass to the next line.

So, after this:

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(mealsrequest);
```

control passes to this:

```
ArrayList<String> strs=new ArrayList<String>();
String mealsnames[]=new String[meals.size()];
```

Now since `meals` is updated on the background thread, you are not able to get the data by the time control reaches `String mealsnames[]=new String[meals.size()];`

So you will get **zero** size (`meals.size()`) here.

Try to move this portion of the code into `onResponse`.

Try like this:

```
public void updateData(){
   ArrayList<String> strs=new ArrayList<String>();
   String mealsnames[]=new String[meals.size()];
   for(int i=0;i<meals.size();i++)strs.add(meals.get(i).getName());
   strs.toArray(mealsnames);
   Log.i("debug","meals ou size "+meals.size());
   CustomList  adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(),mealsnames,meals);
   List = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
   List.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and call this method from `onResponse`:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try{
        JSONObject object= new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray mealsArray = object.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int i=0;i<mealsArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject cur = mealsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int id= cur.getInt("id");
            String name= cur.getString("name");
            String description = cur.getString("description");
            int price = cur.getInt("price");
            meals.add(new meal(id,name,price,description));
        }
        Log.i("debug","meals size = "+meals.size());
        updateData();
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write this  -

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(mealsrequest);
```

That means you are making an asynchronous call and that `mealsrequest` will run on another thread.
You are printing -

```
Log.i("debug","meals ou size "+meals.size());
```

just after you make your `mealsrequest`. When control reaches this statement your network request is not completed yet. So apparently, you don't have anything in your list. Your list will be populated in `onResponse()` only,  since that method is executed after the network request gets completed.