# Scope problem returning ArrayList in method that contains Volley Request

Tags: android, arraylist, scope, android-volley

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558566/volley-how-do-i-return-the-arraylist-from-onresponse-method-in-volley) question as an example, but I did not know where to go with it since I have never seen it before.

I am getting messages from a server that will display in a RecyclerView. Each message is a new instance of a Message class I created. If I hardcode the new Messages, they display fine, however, the strangest part is that the hardcoded **and** the real messages then display together. Comment out the hardcoded messages and they all disappear.

Here are screenshots using list.add and then removing it:

**With manual list.add() included (Two fake and two real messages)**
[image]

**Without manual list.add() removed**
[image]

Here is the class:

```
public class MessagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView messages;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private static final String TAG = "MessagesActivity";
private static final String getMessagesUrl = "https://my_server_url.net/includes/api/mobile_get_messages.php";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static String username;
private static ProgressDialog messagesProgressDialog;
private static ArrayList<Message> list = new ArrayList<>();
private static JSONObject jsonObject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);
    messagesProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MessagesActivity.this, R.style.Custom_Progress_Dialog);
    messagesProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    messagesProgressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Messages...");
    messagesProgressDialog.show();
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    username = sharedPreferences.getString("username", null);
    messages = findViewById(R.id.messages);
    messages.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL));

    ArrayList<Message> messages = initMessages();
    /*
    Tried to use this from the aforementioned link shown above, 
    but didn't know where to go with it.
    */
    //ArrayList<Message> messages = initMessages(new Callback() {
    //    @Override
    //    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Message> list) {

    //    }
    //});

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    this.messages.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    adapter = new MessageAdapter(messages);
    this.messages.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//The currently used method declaration
private ArrayList<Message> initMessages() {

//My attempt to use the suggestion in the link as the method declaration.
//private ArrayList<Message> initMessages(final Callback onCallBack) {
    RequestQueue messagesQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest messagesRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getMessagesUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            messagesProgressDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                String baseUrl = "https://my_server_url.net";
                String defaultbaseUrl = "https://my_server_url.net/css/images/user_default/default_avatar.png";
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: "+response);
                JSONArray responseArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonObject = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String avatar = jsonObject.getString("avatar");
                    String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                    String sender = jsonObject.getString("sender");
                    String timestamp = jsonObject.getString("timestamp");
                    /*
                    Determine if avatar will be user's avatar, or default avatar (they haven't uploaded a new one yet)
                     */
                    if(avatar.contains("../users")) {
                        String substring = avatar.substring(avatar.indexOf(".") + 2);
                        avatar = baseUrl+substring;
                    } else {
                        avatar = defaultbaseUrl;
                    }
                    /*
                    Add each new Message to the list to display
                    They are getting added to the list, but later the
                    list returns 0 for the size.
                     */
                    list.add(new Message(sender, message, avatar, timestamp));
                    //Attempt to use suggestion in link
                    //onCallBack.onSuccess(list);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Messages List Length: "+list.size());
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "EXCEPTION: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            ToastMaker.createLongToast(getApplicationContext(), "VolleyError: "+error.getMessage());
            messagesProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            return params;
        }
    };
    messagesQueue.add(messagesRequest);
    /*
    THIS IS RETURNING 0 FOR THE LIST SIZE :(
     */
    Log.d(TAG, "List Size at bottom of method: "+list.size());
    /*
    Manually adding elements shows the items correctly in RecyclerView, but not by adding them from the response
     */
    //list.add(new Message("testuser", "Hello. This is a fake message", "https://my_server_url.net/css/images/user_default/default_avatar.png", "10:00 pm"));
    //list.add(new Message("testuser2", "Hello. This is another fake message", "https://my_server_url.net/css/images/user_default/default_avatar.png", "12:37 pm"));
    return list;
}
//Suggestion from the link. Currently not used.
//public interface Callback {
//    void onSuccess(ArrayList<Message> list);
//}
```

}

Here are the logs to show that I am getting the correct response back:

```
D/MessagesActivity: Response: {"data":[{"has_read":"yes","avatar":"css\/images\/user_default\/default_avatar.png","sender":"*************","message":"the time is still off","timestamp":"2018-12-12 08:57 PM"},{"has_read":"yes","avatar":"..\/users\/testuser\/uploads\/281007997_1546828047.jpeg","sender":"testuser","message":"Hello, *********. I'm testuser. I like writing code too. ","timestamp":"2018-11-13 08:24 PM"}],"count":2}
```

Here is the Log.d() at the bottom of the method:

```
D/MessagesActivity: List Size at bottom of method: 0
```

But here are the Log.d() statements after adding each new Message object:

```
D/MessagesActivity: Messages List Length: 1
D/MessagesActivity: Messages List Length: 2
```

How can I fix this scope problem? All my data is there.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the code I see two problems at first glance.

1. You are not providing the adapter a `list` to bind the view to.
2. When you receive a new message you are not notifying the adapter that a new Message has been added.

**Problem 1 :**

If you haven't already (or perhaps removed in the pasted code above) you should provide the list to the adapter by calling the appropriate method e.g. `adapter.setAdapterList()`.

**Problem 2 :**

When you receive a new Message simply call `adapter.notifyItemInserted()` and that will ensure that the adapter creates a new `ViewHolder`/`View`.

Comment: adapter.setAdapterList() throws an error. It won't compile now.

Comment: I showed screenshots where the list is showing, but only if I manually add items to my ArrayList. The Volley Request is causing a scope problem, I believe because it's making an Asynchronous request. I just don't know how to place everything in the proper scope.

Comment: Oh, and I will work on the new messages later. I'm just trying to get the initial loading to work. I haven't implemented the notifyItemInserted yet on purpose. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a better suggestion, please feel free to chime in. I discovered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777557/arraylist-being-empty-after-adding-elements) on a similar problem, and when implemented, it works. It shows the correct messages from the database. I created the method updateData() directly under my initMessages() method, like so:

```
public void updateData() {
    ArrayList<Message> strs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        strs.add(list.get(i));
        RecyclerView.Adapter updateAdapter = new MessageAdapter(list);
        messages = findViewById(R.id.messages);
        messages.setAdapter(updateAdapter);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateData() called, List Size: "+list.size());

    }
}
```

Then, at the end of my `onResponse(String response)` method, I simply appended the method call:

```
        /*
        Add each new Message to the list to display
        */
        list.add(new Message(sender, message, avatar, timestamp));
        Log.d(TAG, "Messages List Length: "+list.size());
    }
    updateData(); //<--- Call the method here. It's working!
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "EXCEPTION: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

**Screenshot showing messages being correctly retrieved and displayed**

[image]

Here are the logs from the `Log.d()` statement at the end of `updateData()`

```
D/MessagesActivity: updateData() called, List Size: 2
D/MessagesActivity: updateData() called, List Size: 2
```

So, even though this is "working," per se, if anyone has a better suggestion that would follow proper code convention (if applicable), feel free to let me know. Otherwise, this is working.

**Edit**: I had to override onBackPressed() due to the list being duplicated when returning to the previous activity and loading the MessagesActivity again. Did it like so:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    list.clear();
}
```